# Problems creating my own sudoku backtracking alghoritm (C)

Tags: c, sudoku

I'm trying to make my own sudoku backtracker with C. The program is looping in the Solving Function. It goes into the IsNotInVert and IsNotInHor and then goes back to the beginning of the while loop. (while a != 81) I'm a beginner in C and I guess I started with something way to hard. But anyway I hope on some help.

I try to debug the program following the place in the array where we are now. But it is still hard to follow exactly what the program is doing, I really hope you guys can give me some hints and tips to point me to the right direction!

Here the code;

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_sudoku(int a[9][9]) {
   int i, j, h;
   /* print the sudoku :D */
   for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
         printf("%6i ", a[i][j]);
   }
     printf("|---|---|---|");
   printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
}

/* The solver, 
A counts till 81, 81 is the last number in the puzzle.
If there are no possibilities anymore failed will turn on.
This means we can hop over a static field back.

*/

void Solver (int puzzle[9][9], int staticField[9][9]) { 
int a;
int row;
int col;
int numb;
int failed;
    while(a != 81) {
    if (!IsStatic(row,col,staticField)) {
        do {
        numb++;
        puzzle[row][col] = numb;
        if (numb == 10) {
            a--;
            puzzle[row][col] = 0;
            failed = 1;
            if(col != 0){
            col--;
            }
            else {
                col = 8;
                row--;
            }
        }
        }while(!IsSafe(row,col,puzzle));
            if (col == 9) {
                col = 0;
                if (row != 9) {
                row++;
                } 
            }
        } else if (failed == 0) { a++; }
        else { a--; Solver(puzzle, staticField);}
    } 
    print_sudoku(puzzle);
}

/* If a Number is "static" we are not allowed to change it.
We compare our coordinates with the staticfield "mask" to determine if 
we have a static number.

*/
int IsStatic (int a, int b, int staticField[9][9]) {    
    if (staticField[a][b] == 1 ) {
        return 1;
        }
    else return 0;
}

/* Function who looks if it is allowed to place a number
*/

int IsSafe (int a, int b, int field[9][9]) {
    if (IsNotInVert(a, b, field)) {
        if(IsNotInHor(a, b, field)) {
            if(IsNotInBox(WhichBox(a,b),a,b,field)) {
            return 1;
            } else return 0;
        } else return 0;
    } else return 0;
}


/* 
Function to check if the number we are testing is already in the 3 x 3 box
the if statements (a!=c && b!=d) are to filter yourself out
c= rownumber we want to check
d= columnnumber we want to check
box = array with the numbers in the 3 x 3 box
*/

int IsNotInBox (int coord[1], int c, int d, int field[9][9]) {
    int a = coord[0];
    int b = coord[1];
    int *box[8];

    /* Fill box[] with the numbers in the 3 x 3 box */
    if (a != c && b != d) { box[0] = field[a][b]; }
a++;
    if (a != c && b != d) { box[1] = field[a][b]; }
a++;
    if (a != c && b != d) { box[2] = field[a][b]; }
a - 2;
b++;
    if (a != c && b != d) { box[3] = field[a][b]; }
a++;
    if (a != c && b != d) { box[4] = field[a][b]; }
a++;
    if (a != c && b != d) { box[5] = field[a][b]; }
a - 2;
b++;
    if (a != c && b != d) { box[6] = field[a][b]; } 
a++;
    if (a != c && b != d) { box[7] = field[a][b]; }
a++;
    if (a != c && b != d) { box[8] = field[a][b]; }
    int f;
    for (f = 0; f < 9; f++) {
    if (box[f] == field[c][d]) { return 0; }
    }
    return 1;
}


/* 
To calculate in which 3x3 box you are,

gives back a array with the coordinates of the LEFTCORNER of 
the 3x3 block (4,4 becomes 3,3 8,2 becomes 6,0)

*/

int WhichBox (int a, int b) {
    while (a != 0 || a != 3 || a != 6) { // Make 0,3 or 6
        a--;
    }
    while (b != 0 || b != 3 || b != 6) { // Make 0,3 or 6
        b--;
    }

    int pos[1]; // creating and filling the array
    pos[0] = a;
    pos[1] = b;
    return pos;
}

/*
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! NOT WORKING NOT IMPLEMENTED
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

int IsSolved (int a) {
    if (IsNotInVert(8,  8)) {
        if(IsNotInHor(8, 8)) {
            if(IsNotInBox(WhichBox(8,8),8,8)) {
            return 1;
            } else return 0;
        } else return 0;
    } else return 0;
} 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! NOT WORKING NOT IMPLEMENTED
*/
/*
A is row
B is counter
D is column
~ Same as IsNotInHor
*/

int IsNotInVert (int a, int d, int field[9][9]) {

    int b = 0; // set counter to zero
    for ( b = 0; b < 9; b++) { // For loop till 9
        if (field[d][b] == field[d][a]) { // Check if number is same
            if (a != b ) { // Check if not checking yourself
            return 0;
            }
        }
    } 
    return 1;
}

/*
A = Column
B = Counter
D = Row
*/
int IsNotInHor (int a, int d, int field[8][8]) {

    int b = 0; // set counter to zero
    for ( b = 0; b < 9; b++ ) { // For loop counting till 9 
        if (field[b][a] == field[d][a]) { // Check if number already exist
            if(b != d) { // Check if not checking yourself 
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
        return 1;
}

/*
Main

*/

int main (void) {
    /* Field with the unsolved puzzle */
    int field[9][9] = {
/*       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8              */
/* 0 */ {0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0} ,
/* 1 */ {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 9} ,
/* 2 */ {6, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0} ,
/* 3 */ {0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7} ,
/* 4 */ {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0} ,
/* 5 */ {4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0} ,
/* 6 */ {0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1} ,
/* 7 */ {5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 3, 0} ,
/* 8 */ {0, 8, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0} 
    };

    /* For IsStatic to see where static numbers are */
        int staticField[9][9] = {
/*       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8              */
/* 0 */ {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0} ,
/* 1 */ {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1} ,
/* 2 */ {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0} ,
/* 3 */ {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1} ,
/* 4 */ {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0} ,
/* 5 */ {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0} ,
/* 6 */ {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1} ,
/* 7 */ {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0} ,
/* 8 */ {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0} 
    };
print_sudoku(field);
Solver(field, staticField); 

}
```

Comment: `int a; /*a not initilaized*/ while(a != 81) {` Undefined behavior.

Comment: _But it is still hard to follow exactly what the program is doing_ - I do understand the frustration of a beginner but a word of advice, try to write within your learning curve. Start small.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Interesting fact, [the general solution to solve a sudoku puzzle is NP-Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku).

Comment: This is no debugging service. "But it is still hard to follow exactly what the program is doing" - So you thought about off-loading this boring task to us?